# iOS keyboard pushes content up

Tags: html, css, ios

My code is [open source](https://github.com/JwanKhalaf/Bejebeje.Elm/tree/feature/restyling-search) and that particular branch is [currently deployed](https://bejebeje.com) so you can see what is happening if you have an iPhone.

I've [captured what is happening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3x0t.jpg) to show the problem.

This is only a problem on iOS, I am testing this with my iPhone SE, but I imagine newer iPhones will have the same issue.

On Android, this problem **does not exist**. It looks fine on Android!

[image: android]

The search input should be at the top, ready to receive input from the user.

How can I make it behave the same on iOS? I have already tried:

1. Giving `position: fixed` to the body.
2. I already tried `window.scrollTo(0, 0);` [here](https://github.com/JwanKhalaf/Bejebeje.Elm/blob/feature/restyling-search/src/index.js).

**UPDATE**

I've created a little HTML/CSS file as a playgournd specifically for finding a fix. It is [deployed here](https://vigorous-euclid-f45049.netlify.com/).

Comment: Could [Element.scrollIntoView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) work here? I suppose you'd need to do it in response to a focus event. You'd probably need a port. Not being an iPhone user myself I am curious if this happens with iPhones on other sites as well?

Comment: I'm not sure how you mean @ivarni, the docs on `scrollIntoView` didn't help either, that description of what it does is hard to understand